# How to remove Boot menu page SATA HDD

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

it only appear Boot Menu 1. SATA HDD that's it, the only thing that I can do is to press enter or exit.
I did and nothing happen still appear

Comment: Can you use a photocamera and make a photo of what you see?